# I'm finding errors in my HTML in putting audio it doesn't run

Tags: html

That's my code:

```html
<audio controls>
    <source src="audio.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>
```

I tried putting the code above I expected the output but it didn't bring the output.

Comment: Please provide more details, such as what browser you are using.  Your code seems fine, so it would help if you could give us more information.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with

```
<audio controls src="audio.mp3"\>
```

no, audio type doest need to be specified and most browsers already have libraries for mp3's...

if this still persists - look if you have this audio file and/or you didnt misspelled file name =D